# how to create a menu as the Documentation Center?

Tags: packages, documentation, workbench

I am developing a package in Workbench and for documentation I want to make a menu of options such as the Mathematica documentation center. I could only make templates for guides, tutorials, etc; but I can not find a way to emulate the documentation center. It's possible? Could you guide me on how to solve it? [image: It's possible?]

Comment: Writing the interface will be annoying, but you can set that up using `Grid` and `Panel` or `Button` and friends. Maybe stick in some nine-patch `Appearance` arguments to `Button` if you're feeling really fancy. Next you need to add that notebook to the `"Documentation"` subfolder of your paclet. Then you need to add some `"Metadata"` rules to the `TaggingRules` on your notebook so that the documentation system will open it in the first place. Finally, add the path to the notebook as the `"MainPage"` in the `"Documentation"` element of the `"Extensions"` in the PacletInfo.m file. Easy, right?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try.

Comment: Can a menu like this be built, *not* for documentation purposes, *without* Workbench? For example, click on a `Grid` of `ActionMenu`s populated with functions, select one, and then the notebook/window changes to a new screen with whatever the function does, and finally be able to exit out of that function and return to the start menu, all in the same notebook? Note: I apologize if this is supposed to go in the comment section (I tried but do not have a high enough reputation yet).

Comment: @dynamichedging yup, using `DynamicModule` with a function that changes the interface based on a stored `mode` variable or something

Answer (score 1):

There is git project addressing this question [making mathematica documentation with mathematica](https://b3m2a1.github.io/making-mathematica-documentation-with-mathematica.html#main-content).

This built-in offers a simple start: [`GalleryView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GalleryView.html). It is for publishing HTML over `CloudDeploy`.

The built-in for opening a notebook is [`NotebookOpen`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookOpen.html).

This is the explorative gate to information from the Mathematica directories: [WolframSystemFileOrganization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html).

Creating [CreatingPalettes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html) is a nice alternative as `DynamicModule`.
[Hyperlink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hyperlink.html) is for sure very interesting.

```
Table[Hyperlink["xxx", None, ImageSize -> {100, 40}, 
  Background -> c], {c, {LightBlue, Purple, Gray, Pink}}]
```

[image]

And [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) is great. One step further is [`PasteButton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PasteButton.html):

```
PasteButton /@ CountryData["G8"]
```

[image]

for the use with Wolfram knowledge engine.